# When does a windows workflow process go 'idle'?

Tags: workflow-foundation

When does a windows workflow process go 'idle'?

Does it wait a certain amount of time?  (can this time be changed?)

Or does it go idle immediately when an activity is blocking/listening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workflow instance idles when:

- it is waiting for an external event `(ReceiveActivity` / WCF or `ListenActivity`  / ExternaDataExchange)
- a `DelayActivity` is executing

Further the workflow instance gets persisted when:

- it is in the idle state (see above)
- it is completed or terminated
- a `TransactionScopeActivity` or a `CompensatableTransactionScopeActivity` completes
- the execution of a custom activity marked with the `PersistOnClose` attribute completes
- Unload() (or TryUnload) gets called on it